# Why am I not getting a division error when I set the divisor to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this, the output is 2 and 2, whereas I expected an error since I set @b=0. What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
declare @a int
declare @b int
declare @c int
begin
set @a=10
set @b=5
set @C=@a/@b
print @C
set @b=0
print @C
end
```

The output is 2 and 2, but I expected 2 and error...

Comment: Why do you expect this to error? 10 / 5 = 2 which is what you get. Then you set @b to a new value.

Comment: you should also set @c = @a/@b after setting @b = 0, then you will get the error when you print @c for the second time

Comment: @Dheerendra when I do that, I get 2, then an error message, but then another 2

Comment: yes because @c still holds true for the previous assignment before it has been errored out.

Comment: Most other procedural languages share this feature. Why do you find it surprising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't do any division after you set `@b` to zero.

The line:  `set @C=@a/@b` doesn't set `@C` to a formula that will automatically be calculated any time `@a` or `@b` changes.

It just sets the value of `@c` one time.

TSQL isn't Excel.

Comment: maybe I am a bit slow, but after reading your answer a few times I got what you mean. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting variable to zero after the division so it is not getting the error.

```
declare @a int
declare @b int
declare @c int
begin
set @a=10
set @b=5
set @C=@a/@b --division here
print @C
set @b=0 --setting to zero
set @C=@a/@b --division here will give error
print @C
end
```

It is shown below

[image]

Comment: it still gives me 2, an error message, and another 2

Comment: It executes line by line so it is giving previous values c = 10/2 then error then print @c which has previous values.

Comment: I got it now: the error message refers to SET after I set @b to 0 and *not* to the PRINT! thanks

Comment: I would but the system doesn't let me... "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."